# How to join list of strings?

Tags: python, string

This is probably seriously easy to solve for most of you but I cannot solve this simply putting `str()` around it can I?

I would like to convert this list: `['A','B','C']` into `'A B C'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a list of characters into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481724/convert-a-list-of-characters-into-a-string)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
In [1]: L = ['A', 'B', 'C']
In [2]: " ".join(L)
Out[2]: 'A B C'
```

Comment: just a quick note here: you can use *any* string there and it will join together list items.  So if you wanted to join your items with newlines, you could use `'\n'.join(L)`. or if you wanted to get crazy: `' is crazy! '.join(L)`

Answer (score 0):

I do not like Python's syntax for joining a list of items, so I prefer to call my own function to perform that task, rather than using Python's syntax in line.

Here is my function:

```
def joinList(l, c):
    return c.join(l)


myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
myStrg = joinList(myList, "-")

print myStrg
```

Comment: "Not liking the syntax" is not a very good excuse to write inefficient code.

Comment: Junuxx has a good point.  However, if you REALLY REALLY hate the syntax, you can use the built-in version: `str.join(' ', ['A', 'B', 'C'])`.

Comment: You just quoted the moderator.  My comments were much shorter, even if the code does suck. :/

Comment: @Michael I upvote for this since I don't like python's `''.join` syntax, either. :-) But actually your code not only work on lists, so I suggest change the name to something like joinIter. Or just use `str.join` as @Darthfett suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Let me highlight that [`join`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) is a method of *string*, not one of *list* (actually, it can deal with any *iteratable*, even *dict*s):

```
myList = ['one', 'another', 'next']
separator = ", "
separator.join(myList)
```

will result in

```
'one, another, next'
```