# Best way to split a hexadecimal?

Tags: python, hex

I'm pretty new to hexadecimal in general, and I've got an application that needs me to split a hexadecimal number. For example, given the number 0x607F, I would need to return the high (0x60) or low (0x7F) byte.

This is may implementation, it feels a little cloogy though. Is there a more standard way to do this in python?

```
def byte(integer,highlow):
    assert highlow=='high' or highlow=='low'
    if highlow=='high':
        return hex(int(bin(integer)[:-8],2))
    if highlow=='low':
        return hex(int(bin(integer)[-8:],2))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This returns the high byte and the low byte as a tuple:

```
def bytes(integer):
    return divmod(integer, 0x100)
```

For example:

```
>>> high, low = bytes(0x607F)
>>> hex(high)
'0x60'
>>> hex(low)
'0x7f'
```

BTW, depending on what you need the bytes for, and where the integer came from, there might be much better ways to do what you need.

Comment: Just barely eeked out unutbu's answer on my machine... 1.8us vs 2.22us. FWIW my code was coming in at 4.97us and only calculating just one.

Answer (score 6):

```
def bytes(num):
    return hex(num >> 8), hex(num & 0xFF)

bytes(0x607F)
```

yields

```
('0x60', '0x7f')
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to Ned's answer which is quite correct, [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html) is a powerful tool for extracting bytes.

```
>>> import struct
>>> print("0x%2x 0x%2x\n" % tuple(struct.pack('<H',0x4355)))
0x55 0x43
```

In this example, the "<" tells pack to interpret the input as [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), and the "H" says to expect a 2-byte number.  Struct produces a bytes object (on Python 3), which can then be converted to a tuple to satisfy the string formatting parameters for %x to print out the hex.

Python 2.7 is slightly more cumbersome, only because struct.pack puts the info in a string which must be [split into its characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787/how-to-split-a-string-into-array-of-characters-with-python):

```
>>> print("0x%2x 0x%2x\n" % tuple([ ord(x) for x in struct.pack('<H',0x4355)]))
0x55 0x43
```

If you really *are* doing something as simple as this example, it's probably overkill.  If you're manipulating more values or different lengths of numbers from, for example, registers observed from a microcontroller, or exchanging data with C or C++, consider using struct to make it easier to wrangle the bytes.