# Bitshifting a value in python

Tags: python, byte, swap

I have a value out of I²C register which is 2 bytes wide like 01C5 (as string).
For my application, i have to swap high and low byte.

I tried it this way:

```
valueLow = hex(int(value,16) >> 8)
valueHigh = hex(int(value,16) & 0x0011)
```

but the results I get are now what they should look like.

Do you have a better solution?

Comment: please add the expected result to you question

Comment: The results are `0x1` and `0x1`, of the given snippet

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15036568/2365792)

Comment: Well you're &-ing `C5` with `11`. How is that supposed to work? Use `FF` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the byte-swapped value:

```
swappedValue = hex(value<<8&0xff00 | value>>8&0x00ff)
```

or, if value is a string,

```
swappedValue = hex(int(value,16)<<8&0xff00 |int(value,16)>>8&0x00ff)
```

If you need a number (for I2C), try:

```
swappedValue = int(value,16)<<8&0xff00 | int(value,16)>>8&0x00ff
```

Comment: Thanks that looks very elegant.
But as "value" is a string it generates this message: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'
Unfortunately applying "hex()" to "value" does also generate an error: TypeError: hex() argument can't be converted to hex