# How do i create objects of data in a file ?? python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a file named abc.txt which contains the following data

```
Nathan  Johnson 23 M
Mary    Kom     28 F
John    Keyman  32 M
Edward  Stella  35 M
```

How do i create the objects of the data(records) in the file ?

Code which i have done . I am not getting of jow to create objects of data in a file

```
class Records:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age, gender):
        self.fname = firstname        
        self.lname = lastname 
        self.age = age 
        self.gender = gender
    def read(self):
        f= open("abc.txt","r")
        for lines in f:
            print lines.split("\t")
```

What should i do further ? I am an newbie in python and this task has been given to me. PLease help me out ?

Comment: You would have to read the contents of the file line by line, and split each line by (what looks like) the tab character (`\t`). The resulting list would contain the name at the first and second index, the age at the third index and the gender at the last index.

Comment: You might want to read http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: i have updated the code? now how do i create objects of data in a file ?? Although i can create my own objects with attributes but i want to create objects of the data (records) in an file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you've used an object here, [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) would have been more suitable.

```
# Creating the class
class Records:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age, gender):
        self.fname = firstname
        self.lname = lastname
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

# Using open to open the required file, and calling the file f,
# using with automatically closes the file stream, so its less
# of a hassle.
with open('object_file.txt') as f:
    list_of_records = [Records(*line.split()) for line in f]  # Adding records to a list

for record in list_of_records:
    print record.age  # Printing a sample
```

Comment: Records are already there in the file, i just need to make there objects and depending upon the firstname, lastname, age or gender, i will make a search

Comment: what does this * do ??

Comment: @Johnjohn Its called the splat [operator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: what does it do here beside from splitting ?

Comment: @Johnjohn Please read the documentation and the code samples, under "Unpacking Argument Lists". It will explain everything.

Comment: @Johnjohn This might be helpful [too](http://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments). Get in the habbit of reading documentation and articles about things you don't know.

Comment: ok..so here *line.split() packs all the records of line from a file and store it in a variable ......

Comment: @Johnjohn Well `line.split()` splits the line by spaces. `*`, then unpacks the different variables that are now contained within the list, and makes them parameters to your `Record`'s constructor.

Comment: is the list_of_records are my object to Record class ?? or its a list?? To what I understand I consider it as a list which holds the records of an file

Comment: @Johnjohn Its called `list_of_records`. Its a list. Its a list that contains your record objects. I've written the code, so that all the records in a particular file, are made into Records, and then added to a list.

Comment: give me sometime to understand. If i'll have aquery i will add the comment. I am jus a newbie so I might ask some silly question. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Johnjohn Well _try_ reading some documentation. I know you are a newbie, thats why I'm being patient with you. But say [`split()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787/how-to-split-a-string-into-array-of-characters-with-python/4978792#4978792) and how it works, already has an answer here on SO.

Comment: Ok. so each record in an file is my object and those objects are being getting into the list one by one. isn't it ?

Comment: @Johnjohn Absolutely right.

Comment: I have some more questions to come. Give me 30 mins i will read it first and then ask it..? Again thank you in advance :)

Comment: Now do this fname, lname, age, gender have an index associated with them ?? Because my requirement is that if the user select t search criteria through firstname it should search in firstname column  only  and display the whole record.

Comment: @Johnjohn Then that is a separate question all together. We should not be making the comments any longer than they already are :P Ask a separate question.

Comment: Ok...and thank you for the concepts above. I am raising an seperate question. Plesae do reply on that

Comment: @Johnjohn Sure, happy to.

Comment: @ Games Brainiac : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490587