# Tuplify a number

Tags: python

```
def tuplify(number):
    x = str(number)
    if len(x) <= 0:
        return 0
    lst = []
    for i in range(0,10):
        if i == x[len(x)-1]:
            lst.append(i)
        return tuple(lst)
```

This is my code and I can't get the output I want.

`tuplify(102486)` which should give me `(1, 0, 2, 4, 8, 6)`

Comment: You probably should return the result outside of your loop. Also, what's wrong with `tuple(str(number))`?

Comment: Is it this you want: `tuple(int(i) for i in str(1234))`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That should be an answer, obviously. Brilliant.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the slight problem being it will return `('1','2','3')` not `(1,2,3)`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, absolutely, but the questioner's current code tries to generate a tuple of strings, so I ran with that.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert that to a tuple of numbers like this

```
print tuple(map(int, str(102486)))
# (1, 0, 2, 4, 8, 6)
```

But note that, leading zeros in the number will NOT be retained.

Apart from the fact that you are comparing a string and a number,

```
if i == x[len(x)-1]:
```

you are always comparing `i` with the last element.

Also, you wanted to return a tuple, but if the string is empty, then you are returning zero

```
if len(x) <= 0:
    return 0
```

instead, an empty tuple would have been appropriate

```
if len(x) == 0:
    return ()
```

Answer (score 2):

Edited :

```
>>> p = 123434455
>>> tuple(int(i) for i in str(p))
(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5)
>>>
```

Comment: Does not help with his problems, and is even the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code, one is this:

```
 if i == x[len(x)-1]:
```

As `i` is an integer, but `x` is a string, this is never going to be true. `1` is not equal to `"1"`.

You,r `return tuple(lst)` is also indented so that it is inside the for loop, but it shouldn't be.

But the for loop is completely strange too -- you loop over numbers 0 to 9, and always compare to the last character of `x`, why? What is it trying to do?

There are one-liner ways to do this but I don't think those help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at :

1. [Converting integer to string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python)
2. [How to split a string into array of characters with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787/how-to-split-a-string-into-array-of-characters-with-python)
3. http://www.u.arizona.edu/~erdmann/mse350/topics/list_comprehensions.html (on map section)

you can cast your number to a string, split it and convert each char back to a int

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code.

First you don't need to check the length, because there is no such thing as a "blank" number; so what you need to check is if a number was sent or not. Also you are returning `0` which is not a tuple.

Second, you don't need a list because you can step through a string directly.

Finally, your result will be a tuple of *strings*, when you need a tuple of integers.

Combining this, you get:

```
def tuplify(number):
    if not number:
       return ()  # this is an empty tuple
    x = str(number)
    return tuple(map(int,x))
```

Comment: Actually `()` is an empty tuple, `(,)` is a syntax error. Confusingly, `(1,)` is the way to write a one-element tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
>>> def tuplify(number):
    t=tuple()
    number=str(number)
    for i in number:
        t+=tuple(i)
    return t

>>> tuplify(123456)
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')
>>>
```