# How to split a string into characters and assign each character to a separate variable

Tags: python, string

I need to split a 4-digit string number into 4 1-digit strings.

The number looks like this: `num = "1234"`

I need so split it to separate variables: `a = "1"`, `b = "2"`, `c = "3"`, and `d = "4"`, so I can later reform it as: `print (str(a) + ',' + str(b) + str(c) + str(d))`.

P.S. please don't tell me how to add a comma between "a" and "b", I need the variables for later.

Answer (score 8):

You can use *iterable unpacking*:

```
a, b, c, d = num
```

given these are strings. But usually it is better to *use a list*, since then you can handle strings with arbitrary length:

```
chars = list(num)
```

This works since a string is an iterable of characters. So you can unpack them with iterable unpacking, or use the `list` constructor, which takes an iterable and creates a list with the elements of the iterable.