# Which separator to use in order to unpack a string to single chars

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to separate a string that looks like this: `'O,t'` `'R,p'` `'A/d'` etc.
The string will be a user's input, therefore I wish to use the join function and unpacking.

Which separator should I use?
Obviously this doesn't work because there are no spaces:

```
user_input = 'O,t'
a,b,c = user_input.split('')

# Output should be:
# a = 'O', b = ',' , c = 't'
```

I want to **avoid** using `list(user_input)` if possible.

Comment: What about `a, b, c = user_input` ?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the obvious and correct way of doing it? You can use `[c for c in user_input]` too, but that's just being obtuse and verbose for no good reason.

Comment: and khelwood is correct, if all you are doing is assigning to separate variables, then just use `a, b, c = user_input`. Any iterable will do to unpack, and strings are iterables.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `list`?

Comment: "but that's just being obtuse and verbose" :) Well, no. That's just being new to python. I didn't realize the join is actually unnecessary here. Thanks for your help. I now understand where I went wrong

Comment: A better duplicate target: [How to split a string into characters and assign each character to a separate variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47501324/7851470)