# How do I split a string into an array of characters in python?

Tags: python

I have a variable like this:

```
bug = "^bug:url1.com;url2.com;url3.com;url4.com^"
```

And I want the end result to be like this:

```
bug = ["url1.com","url2.com","url3.com","url4.com"]
```

I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

bug = "^bug:url1.com;url2.com;url3.com;url4.com^"
bug = bug.split(";")
print bug
```

But it outputs:

```
['^bug:url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com', 'url4.com^']
```

Please note that the variable `bug` consists of a bunch of URLs not just ordinary words, maybe with regex ? I don't know sorry I'm still new to programming, please help me fix this.

Comment: `bug[5:-1].split(';')` ?

Comment: If you want to cut off `^bug:` from the beginning and `^` from the end, write `bug = bug[5:-1]` and then split with `bug.split(';')`

Comment: That's not an array of characters; it's an array of strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into an array of characters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-of-characters-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I think the existing answers are too complicated for this simple task so I'm posting my comment as an answer:

```
>>> bug = "^bug:url1.com;url2.com;url3.com;url4.com^"
>>> bug[5:-1].split(';')
['url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com', 'url4.com']
```

You slice the unwanted characters from the beginning and end of your string and afterwards you split the string by your delimiter `;`. Of course, if there's anything dynamic about the format of your string, e.g. it could start with `'^someunwantedtext:'`, then use a regular expression.

Comment: Problem is "*the variable bug consists of a bunch of URLs not just ordinary words*" so `bug` might not be always of the same size. Your solution will only work if you know the length of URLs which if I understand well is not the case here.

Comment: @Nuageux no, this solution is independent from the length of the urls. You discard the first 5 and the last character from the string. What's in between does not matter.

Comment: My mistake you are right. I misunderstood some part of the question. I thought that "bug" could be something else that just "bug".  I'm not a native english speaker, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First, split to remove part before ':' and to remove part after '^'.
Then split for each ';'

```
bug = "^bug:url1.com;url2.com;url3.com;url4.com^"
bug = bug.split(":")[1:][0].split("^")[:-1][0]
bug = bug.split(";")
print bug
# ['url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com', 'url4.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lstrip()` and `rstrip()`.
This way you could even have ^ and bug inside the url and it won't be stripped.

```
bug = "^bug:url1.com;url2.com;url3.com;url4.com^"
buglist = bug.lstrip("^bug").lstrip(":").rstrip("^").split(";")
```

Output: `['url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com', 'url4.com']`

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use regex for this purpose! replace the bug and special character in your data and split the urls with `;`

```
import re
bug = "^hi.com;hi.com:url1.com;url2.com;url3.com;url4.com^"
print re.sub(r'((\w+.com;?)*:)|\^','',bug).split(';')
```

Output:

```
['url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com', 'url4.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of **replace** and **split** does the job:

```
>>> s = "^bug:url1.com;url2.com;url3.com;url4.com^"
>>> s.replace('^','').replace('bug:','').split(';')
['url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com', 'url4.com']
```

**Step-by-step explanation**

```
>>> s.replace('^','')
'bug:url1.com;url2.com;url3.com;url4.com'
>>> s.replace('^','').replace('bug:','')
'url1.com;url2.com;url3.com;url4.com'
>>> s.replace('^','').replace('bug:','').split(';')
['url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com', 'url4.com']
>>>
```

**A better solution**

As timgeb mentioned my method fails if the urls contain the string "bug:". timgeb's solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43939538/2194843) seems to be fine:

```
>>> s[5:-1].split(';')
['url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com', 'url4.com']
```

Comment: Will fail if any url contains the substring `'bug:'`.