# Converting a string into a list of its individual chars

Tags: python-3.x

How can I take a string such as "hello world" and turn it into a list of its chars?

I have some code that managed to work but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way that involves less code.

Here's what I have:

```
stringOne = "Hello World" 
stringOneList = []

for i in stringOne:
    stringOneList.append(i)

print(stringOneList)
```

this results in an output of ['h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d'] which IS what I'm after. But it feels clunky. Is there a function I'm missing that would do this more efficiently?

Comment: `list("Hello World")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string into array of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787/how-to-split-a-string-into-array-of-characters)

Answer (score 2):

```
examplestring = "asdfg"

a = list(examplestring)

print(a)
```

gives:

```
['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```