# How to split "\t" in a string to two separate characters as "\" and "t"? (How to split Escape Sequence?)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to split a string in python into a list of characters. I know that there are a lot of ways to do this in python, but I have a case where those methods don't give me the desired results.

The problem happens when I have special characters like '\t' that is explicitly written in the string (and I don't mean the real tab).

Example:

```
string = "    Hello \t World."
```

the output I need is:

```
list_of_chars = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', '\', 't', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '.']
```

but when I use the methods that are given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787/how-to-split-a-string-into-array-of-characters), I get a list that contains '/t' as whole string - not separated.

Example:

```
> list(string)
> ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', ' ', '\t', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '.']
```

I want to know why this happens and how to get what I want.

Comment: `string = [x for x in r"    Hello \t World."]` is the closest you'll get.

Comment: The output you need is impossible. That's a syntax error.

Comment: If you typed `"    Hello \t World."` in Python, this is the real tab. A string containing backslash-t would be either `r"    Hello \t World."` or `"    Hello \\t World."`. Do you have the string in the code or are you reading a file?...

Comment: @dividebyzero I am reading a source code file of a high-level like language, and it have strings like the one I mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can substitute your string accordingly:

```
import itertools
txt = "    Hello \t World."

specials = { 
    '\a' : '\\a', #     ASCII Bell (BEL)
    '\b' : '\\b', #     ASCII Backspace (BS)
    '\f' : '\\f', #     ASCII Formfeed (FF)
    '\n' : '\\n', #     ASCII Linefeed (LF)
    '\r' : '\\r', #     ASCII Carriage Return (CR)
    '\t' : '\\t', #     ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB)
    '\v' : '\\v'  #     ASCII Vertical Tab (VT)
}

# edited out: # txt2 = "".join([x if x not in specials else specials[x] for x in txt])
txt2 = itertools.chain(* [(list(specials[x]) if x in specials else [x]) for x in txt])

print(list(txt2))
```

Output:

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', '\\', 't', ' ', 'W', 
 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '.']
```

The list comprehension looks more  "positive" and uses `list(itertools.chain(*[...]))` instead of `list("".join([...]))` which should be more performant.

Comment: @vaultah Cool. Only new about `[key]` and `.keys` - a `.get()` with a default - should have thought it would be provided. Found it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict. I read about the ["flatten inner lists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) syntax but cant get my head around it. Thanks for commenting - gonna read up on translate next.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at [String Literal](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) document, which says:

> The backslash (`\`) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character. String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter `r' or`R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for backslash escape sequences.

In your example string, `\t` are not two characters but a single character which represents *ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB)*.

In order to tell your Python interpreter that these two are separate character, you should be using raw string (using **r** before string **""**)as:

```
>>> list(r"    Hello \t World.")
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', '\\', 't', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '.']
```

But here also you'll see two `\\` in the resultant list, which is just a Python's way of representing `\`.

For Python interpreter `'\'` is an invalid string because `\'` in a string represent *Single quote (')*. Hence, when you do `'\'`, it raises below error because for Python there is no end quote present in the string:

```
>>> '\'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    '\'
      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

---

If you can't declare your string as raw string (as it's already defined or imported from some other source), you may convert it to byte string by setting encoding as "unicode-escape":

```
>>> my_str = "    Hello \t World."

>>> unicode_escaped_string = my_str.encode('unicode-escape')
>>> unicode_escaped_string
b'    Hello \\t World.'
```

Since it is a byte-string, you need to call [**`chr`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) to get the corresponding character value of each byte. For example:

```
>>> list(map(chr, unicode_escaped_string))
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', '\\', 't', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '.']
```

Answer (score 4):

You could maybe convert to a Python's literal string and then split character by character?

```
string = "    Hello \t World."
string_raw = string.encode('unicode-escape')
print([ch for ch in string_raw])
print([chr(ch) for ch in string_raw])
```

Outputs:

```
[32, 32, 32, 32, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 92, 116, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 46]
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', '\\', 't', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '.']
```

The Ascii `92` is a single backlash, even though when you print it in a terminal, it'll show it escaped.

Answer (score -1):

`\t` means tab, if you want to explicitely have a `\` character, you'll need to escape it in your string:

```
string = "    Hello \\t World."
```

Or use a raw string:

```
string = r"    Hello \t World."
```