# User input as a list of integers in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

I have this python 3 script which should compare two lists and find equal numbers. It'a a Cows and Bulls game. Not going to go too much into details but here is the problem. When I ask for user input as a list it returns list of Strings and not integers, hence I can't compare elements with my given list if integers. Please advise how to cast `userinput` list into list of digits: Script below:

```
import random

numtoguess = [random.randrange(0,10,1) for _ in range (4)]
print(numtoguess)

userinput = []

while numtoguess != userinput:
    userinput = list(input("Welcome to Cows and Bulls game!!! \nGuess the random 4 digit number :> "))
    print(userinput)
    cows = 0
    bulls = 0
    counter = 0
    for i in userinput:
        if i in numtoguess and i == numtoguess[counter]:
            bulls += 1
        elif i in numtoguess and i != numtoguess[counter]:
            cows += 1
        counter += 1
    print('Cows: ' + str(cows))
    print('Bulls: ' + str(bulls))
```

Comment: do `userinput = [int(x) for x in input("Welcome to Cows and Bulls game!!! \nGuess the random 4 digit number :> ")]`

Comment: @Aran-Fey. Close but the duplicate splits the number "words", doesn't iterate on the chars

Comment: Meh. We can add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787/how-to-split-a-string-into-array-of-characters) to the list, then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert all strings in a list to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `int()` function to cast strings to integers, provided the string can be implicitly converted. Most commonly I see user input as integers in the following format:

```
num = int(input("enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
userinput = list(input("Welcome to Cows and Bulls game!!! \nGuess the random 4 digit number :> "))
```

creates a list with each char of the input string (the digits, but as string).

Just convert to integer with a list comprehension:

```
userinput = [int(x) for x in input("Welcome to Cows and Bulls game!!! \nGuess the random 4 digit number :> ")]
```

Comment: Shoot, you got it just before me. I'll remove.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it this way.

```
userinput = list(input("Welcome to Cows and Bulls game!!! \nGuess the random 4 digit number :> "))
userinput = [int(i) for i in userinput]
```

Comment: you don't have to convert to `list`, just iterate on the characters.

Comment: @pstatix or not. Self-answered questions are okay if future readers can benefit from them.

Comment: I can't delete it

Answer (score 0):

During each iteration you could append the input to the list as an int...

```
userinput.append(int(input("enter num")))
```

Comment: that forces the user to type digit+return x times.