# How to split an integer and return it as a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python and I wanted to know how I would convert an input `n = 123` to a list `[1,2,3]`

This is the code I have and I'm getting errors:

```
def digitize(n):
  return n.split()
```

My error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

**Edit: This question is a duplicate**

Comment: `print([int(i) for i in str(n)])` ?

Comment: how are you passing your input? are you using `input()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as this:

```
n = 1234
mylist = [int(x) for x in str(n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def digitize(n):
    return [int(d) for d in str(n)]


print(digitize(123))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

First convert it to a string, using [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) then iterate over the characters of the string (the digits) and transform each back to an integer. As an alternative you could also use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), for example:

```
return [e for e in map(int, str(n))]
```

Or as pointed by @Ev.Kounis you could simply do:

```
return list(map(int, str(n)))
```

Comment: Thanks , this works perfectly

Comment: the `return [e for e in map(int, str(n))]` is too verbose. `return list(map(int, str(n)))` would do too.

Answer (score 0):

In python split is a method of strings, not integers.

Convert the integer to string first and then transform it to [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787/how-to-split-a-string-into-array-of-characters) of characters:

```
list(str(123)) # ['1', '2', '3']
```

You can then map each element to int again:

```
list(map(int,list(str(123))))  # [1, 2, 3]
```