# How do I break down a word already in a list into individual characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For example if it is `["aba"]` how do I break it into `["a", "b","a"]`?

Comment: Just call `list("aba")`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into array of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787/how-to-split-a-string-into-array-of-characters)

Answer (score 1):

One of many possible ways:

```
lst = ["aba"]
result = [char for char in lst[0]]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is always from 1st element of the list:

```
splits = [i for i in a[0]]
```