# Splitting a string that is converted to a list with a single item into multiple items

Tags: python, list, indexing, split, whitespace

I have a string that is converted to a list using the split() function, and I want to split my single item into multiple items each containing one character.

Here's my code:

```
string = "ABCDEFG"
x = string.split()
print(x)
```

Thank you for your time!:D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question will be clearer, and will attract better answers, if you include: 1. the output do you get when you run the code you have, and 2. the correct output you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into array of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787/how-to-split-a-string-into-array-of-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.split(separator, maxsplit)` method returns a list of strings after breaking the given string by the specified separator.

*separator*: The is a delimiter. The string splits at this specified separator. It is not provided then any white space is a separator.

*maxsplit*: It is a number, which tells us to split the string into a maximum of the provided number of times. If it is not provided then there is no limit.

You can do this if you want to split it into a list of single characters.

```
x='ABCDEFG'
char_list=list(x)
#['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
```

---

If you want to split it into single characters avoiding any spaces then try this.

```
x='abcde fgh   i'
out=[char for string in x.split() for char in string]
#['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

And `.split()` doesn't convert your string to a list. In your, it returned `['ABCDEFG]` because the string contains no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `for` loop :

```
# Driver code 
string = "ABCDEFG"
print(split([char for char in string]))
```

Or the `list`:

```
string = "ABCDEFG"
print(list(string))
```