# How to make a list of letters from an alphabet string

Tags: python, string, list

If I have a string

```
alph = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

and I want to make a list like

```
alph = ["A", "B", "C", ...]
```

How would I do it?

Comment: Should've closed it as a duplicate of [How to split a string into array of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4978787/7851470)

Answer (score 4):

python already gives us the uppercase letters as a string we can convert it to a list.

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase
print(list(ascii_uppercase))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
list(alph)
```

Output:

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z]
```