# List comprehensions in python

Tags: python, list

Is there any way I can combine two list a and b into c using list comprehensions in python,

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=['a','b']

c=['1a','1b','2a','2b','3a','3b']
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python) (also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481724/python-convert-list-of-char-into-string).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = ['a', 'b']
>>> c = ['%d%c' % (x, y) for x in a for y in b]
>>> c
['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b']
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=['a','b']
>>> ['%d%s' % el for el in product(a,b)]
['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b']
```

With new string formatting

```
>>> ['{0}{1}'.format(*el) for el in product(a,b)]
['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b']
```

Comment: +1 This is a better solution as product will be far more efficient than nested loops, and more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

use `c = ["%d%s" % (x,y) for x in a for y in b]`

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions can loop over multiple objects.

```
In[3]: [str(a1)+b1 for a1 in a for b1 in b]

Out[3]: ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b']
```

Note the slight subtlety of converting the number into a string.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the "nested" version.

```
c = [str(i) + j for i in a for j in b]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
c=[str(r)+s for r,s in itertools.product(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

somewhat similar version of jamylak's solution:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=['a','b']
>>>[str(x[0])+x[1] for x in itertools.product(a,b)]
['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b']
```