# Convert a list of integers to string

Tags: python, string, list, int

I want to convert my list of integers into a string.  Here is how I create the list of integers:

```
new = [0] * 6
for i in range(6):
    new[i] = random.randint(0,10)
```

Like this:

```
new == [1,2,3,4,5,6]
output == '123456'
```

Comment: `new = [ random.randint(0,10) for i in range(6) ]` would be simpler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's definitely a slicker way to do this, but here's a very straight forward way:

```
mystring = ""

for digit in new:
    mystring += str(digit)
```

Answer (score 70):

With [Convert a list of characters into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481724/convert-a-list-of-characters-into-a-string) you can just do

```
''.join(map(str,new))
```

Comment: Or for the `map`-averse, `''.join([str(x) for x in new])`.

Comment: Or even `''.join(str(random.randint(0, 10)) for i in range(10))`

Answer (score 12):

Two simple ways of doing this:

```py
"".join(map(str, A))
"".join(str(a) for a in A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming a bit late and somehow extending the question, but you could leverage the `array` module and use:

```
from array import array

array('B', new).tobytes()

b'\n\t\x05\x00\x06\x05'
```

In practice, it creates an array of 1-byte wide integers (argument `'B'`) from your list of integers. The array is then converted to a string as a binary data structure, so the output won't look as you expect (you can fix this point with `decode()`). Yet, it should be one of the fastest integer-to-string conversion methods and it should save some memory. See also documentation and related questions:

https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/

https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array

[Converting integer to string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: Maybe python 3 only? tobytes not available for me in python 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```py
new = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

output = "".join(str(i) for i in new)
# '123456'
```

Keep in mind, [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) accepts an *iterable* so there's no need to convert the argument to a `list`.

Answer (score -4):

You can loop through the integers in the list while converting to string type and appending to "string" variable.

```
for int in list:
    string += str(int)
```

Comment: Its totally different

Comment: in what way, can you please help me.

Comment: @Cherry your code is exactly the same, changing variable names does not make the code different

Comment: Plus, this is very bad practice. Never use reserved names as variable names.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Its different, its just that you cannot see

Comment: @Fejs Thats how you code and this is how i code, not a bad practice in my perspective

Comment: Please read this short answer: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-reserved-word-and-variable-name There is no perspective, that's the fact.

Comment: @Fejs Theres a perspective for everything on how you see things.