# Given a list of tuples, return a string by concatenation

Tags: python, string, list, function

```
def display(xs):
    string1 = ''
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        string1+=str(xs[i])+'-'
    return string1
```

Given a list of tuples as `xs = [(2,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)]`.Return this list as a string, by adding them up with dashes '-'.

So I wan to return a string that looks something like `'(2,3)-(4,4)-(5,5)-(6,6)'`.

What my code does is it correctly adds the dashes but the errors I am getting is that is doesn't read in the first value and it also ends up with an extra dash at the end.

My code returns a string that looks like `'(4,4)-(5,5)-(6,6)-'` which is wrong. I have shown my code above and need help fixing this.

Comment: Why don't you use `.join()` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list of characters into a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481724/convert-a-list-of-characters-into-a-string)

Comment: please do some research .. it is a duplicate ...

Comment: When testing your code it does "read" the first tuple correctly.
By the way, using `for i in range(len(xs))` and then `xs[i]` is redundant. Instead, simply do `for tup in xs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. However, it'd be better to use `.join()` in this case to not append `-` to the last tuple in the list:

```
>>> def display(xs):
...    return "-".join(map(str, xs))

>>> display([(2,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)])
'(2, 3)-(4, 4)-(5, 5)-(6, 6)'
```

If you don't want the whitespace between tuple items, you gotta format them yourself:

```
>>> def display(xs):
...     return "-".join("({},{})".format(*t) for t in xs)

>>> display([(2,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)])
'(2,3)-(4,4)-(5,5)-(6,6)'
```

Here is the modified version of your function:

```
>>> def display(xs):
...     string1 = ""
...     for i in range(len(xs)):
...         string1 += str(xs[i])
...         if i != len(xs) - 1:
...             string1 += "-"
...     return string1
```