# Python: extract items in sublist into string

Tags: python, string, list, sublist

I got a list like this:

```
[['zai4'], [' '], ['tui1'], ['jin4'], [' '], ['shi2'], ['pin3'], [' '], ['an1'], ['quan2'], [' '], ['xin4'], ['xi1'], [' ']]
```

how could I convert it into this kind:

```
zai4 tui1 jin4 shi2 pin3 an1 quan2 xin4 xi1
```

Thank you.

I think the unique part of my question is how to extract content from
sub-list into string.

Comment: Please post your tried code.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of  [Convert a list of characters into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481724/convert-a-list-of-characters-into-a-string)

Comment: `for items in text: for item in items: new_list.append(item)`, then the new_list should be like zai4 tui1 jin4 shi2 pin3 an1 quan2 xin4 xi1. Is this correct? @Atiq

Comment: Assuming your list in variable `l`. I might do:` [y for x in l for y in x if y != ' ']`

Comment: Do you want another list? or just plain string separated  by space?

Comment: Thank you so much. :) I need a plain string separated by space only. Ayodhyankit Paul's answer helps me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
data=[['zai4'], [' '], ['tui1'], ['jin4'], [' '], ['shi2'], ['pin3'], [' '], ['an1'], ['quan2'], [' '], ['xin4'], ['xi1'], [' ']]



print([i[0] for i in data if i[0].isalnum()])
```

output:

```
['zai4', 'tui1', 'jin4', 'shi2', 'pin3', 'an1', 'quan2', 'xin4', 'xi1']
```

if you want without list then:

```
print(" ".join([i[0] for i in data if i[0].isalnum()]))
```

output:

```
zai4 tui1 jin4 shi2 pin3 an1 quan2 xin4 xi1
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. What if I want to save the output as a list form? Such as ['zai4 tui1 jin4 shi2 pin3 an1 quan2 xin4 xi1'], but not in string.

Answer (score 0):

Using `list comprehension` and `str.join`

```
a = [['zai4'], [' '], ['tui1'], ['jin4'], [' '], ['shi2'], ['pin3'], [' '], ['an1'], ['quan2'], [' '], ['xin4'], ['xi1'], [' ']]
print(" ".join(i[0] for i in a).replace("  ", ""))
```

**Output:**

```
zai4 tui1 jin4 shi2 pin3 an1 quan2 xin4 xi1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpacking:

```
s = [['zai4'], [' '], ['tui1'], ['jin4'], [' '], ['shi2'], ['pin3'], [' '], ['an1'], ['quan2'], [' '], ['xin4'], ['xi1'], [' ']]
new_s = ' '.join(a for [a] in s if a != ' ')
```

Output:

```
'zai4 tui1 jin4 shi2 pin3 an1 quan2 xin4 xi1'
```