# How to generate random values from a string in python?

Tags: python, random

I have a string `'ABCDEF'`, I would like 4 *unique* characters to be generated randomly every time I run the program.

The result should give something like:

```
BDAF

EDCB

CAFE

...
```

I could use `random.sample` but it would require a `list` to be used instead, are there ways of achieving the same result using a `string`?

Comment: `random.sample` works perfectly fine with strings. And you can easily convert the list it returns to a string, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list of characters into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481724/convert-a-list-of-characters-into-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use `random.sample`; it'll give you a list, but it's easy enough to join the resulting list into a string:

```
result = ''.join(random.sample("ABCDEF", 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions provided by Python's [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module.
Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to extract a random set of characters from the string and then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them:

```
import random
source = "ABCDEFG"
result = "".join(random.sample(source, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) then join your resulting list with '' to create a string:

```
import random
c = "ABCDEF"
''.join(random.sample(c, 4))
```

For input, you can use a string as in Python a string is also a list (list of characters)

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 solutions (and probably 100 more):

1. The"classic" `for` method appending everyone of the `N=4` letters to the same string and the `choice` method of the `random` module that picks one element among its arguments,
2. Using the `join` `method` to add in one time the elements generated by the `choices` method of the `random` module. The `choices` method is very versatile and can be used with several arguments ([official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)),
3. Using the `join` `method` to add in one time the elements generated by the `sample` method of the `random` module. The `sample(set,num)`method picks randomly `num` elements in `set`.

---

```
import random
N=4
source_string = 'ABCDEF
```

Method1

```
random_string_1=""
for it in range(0,N):
    random_string_1 = random_string_1 + random.choice(source_string)
```

Method2

```
random_string_2 = "".join(random.choices(source_string, weights=None, 
cum_weights=None, k=N))
```

Method3

```
random_string_3 = "".join(random.sample(source_string, N))
```

Comment: This answer seems quite ok. But it would be nice if you can add some explanations as well. This would improve the quality of the answer.

Comment: The OP wanted to pick 4 unique characters from the string "ABCDEF". Your code doesn't do that.

Comment: I have modified my answer accordingly