# Cannot re-arrange string in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to work through this Leetcode challenge. Basically, this is the problem:
[image]

I am given a string `codeleet` and list if integers `[4,5,6,7,0,2,1,3]` and I have to sort the indeces from 0 to n and thereby re-arranging the letters to get `leetcode`. This is my code. I am just appending every letter from `s` to `output` by making sure I am reaching the ith element of the letter corresponding to the indices:

```
class Solution:
    def restoreString(self, s: str, indices: List[int]) -> str:
        output = ''
        
        # append to output each character starting from index 0
        
        for i in range(0, len(indices)):
            output += s[indices[i]]
        print(output)
```

But this is the output of the test case:

```
leetcdoe
```

It rearranges most of it correctly but then it messes up. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encoding the string, not decoding it. It is totally accidental that the first few letters are correctly in place. If you execute your code step by step using a pen and paper you'll see it.

Try this:

```
for i in sorted(indices):
    output += s[indices.index(i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

An overthinking solution...

```
def restore_str(s, indices):
    dictionary = dict(zip(indices, s))
    _, word = zip(*sorted(dictionary.items()))
    return ''.join(word)
```

First read the `indices` and characters in `s`, through a zip, see [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Then cast the two list into a dict [How do I convert two lists into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/how-do-i-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Then sort the dictionary since by the indices.

Finally read the 2nd element in each of each item returned from `dictionary.items()` using `zip(*sorted(...))`

Then join all the characters in the word, [Convert a list of characters into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481724/convert-a-list-of-characters-into-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

The following will get the correct string

```
''.join(c for _, c in sorted(zip(indices, s))
```

Zipping the indices with the string and then sorting will give you a list of tuples where the second element of each tuple is the char in the correct position

Then you use `''.join` to join together the second element of each tuple