# How to create a variable containing input from a list in Python

Tags: python

I've a lists containing .las Files of different length. I couldn't figure out how it is possible to create a variable containing all the list entries separated by a ";"  ?

Thanks for your help,

Mauro

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join list of strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426988/how-to-join-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 3):

Well am not sure if I get you but:

```
some_list = ['file.las', 'another_file.las', 'something.las']
e = ';'.join(some_list)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped out. Would you also know how to add a path before every list entry? Something like:  Add: path2+"\\" to every list entry resulting in a "new list" on which I can do the ';'.join(some_list). Thanks

Comment: ';'.join(map(lambda list_entry:path2+'\'+list_entry,list))

Comment: As @Frost.baka explained but I'd also add os.path.join(path2, list_entry). That way you don't have to think on which OS you are.