# How can I convert words in [ ] to words in line?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to join list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426988/how-to-join-list-of-strings)

I have a couple of functions in a module to run. First, I have to use `read()` to read strings in a document and save it as new_string and run a function. Then, I need to read a document using `readlines()`. After running the first function like `match = clean_passage(new_string)` then match contains `['/n', 'asdf', 'dfg']`. Now, I need them in a line as it is shown in the original document. So, asdf dfg. How can I convet match into a thing that contains strings in a similar fashion that we get when we read a document using `readlines()`.

So far, to do this, I had to save it and then open it using `readlines()`, which takes time. Is there any way to do that using a simple command? Sorry if the explanation is not clear.

Comment: You should always show what have you tried so far, so you can get quick help!

Comment: @Curious. He did :D He said he saves the list to a file and reads it back in.

Comment: @trideceth12: I meant code! :)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
to_convert  =  ['/n', 'asdf', 'dfg']

original_line = " ".join(to_convert)
```