# How to get values in python list and combined into one variable - python

Tags: python, database, list, extract

I would like to create a variable named "allvar" that has all values in mylist
for example :

```
mylist = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

How can I create allvar to be something like .. X Y Z seperated by one space instead of "," 
and without [] and with out "single quote"

```
allvar = X Y Z
```

The reason I like to get allvar because I need to pass this allvar to another host server that have this format already in place ..

Any recommendation ?

Comment: without single quotes makes it a variable, that too a invalid one.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? ...you can't since this X Y Z isn't a valid datatype.

Comment: I said I need to pass this value to another server, because list can't be used to pass to another server. X Y Z meaning String , so I'm actually looking for something like 'X Y Z'

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more cleared.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of ["how to join list of strings."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426988/how-to-join-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use join:

```
>>> mylist = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> allvar = ' '.join(mylist)
>>> print allvar
X Y Z
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do here.  If you are just trying to send the string 'X Y Z' with X Y and Z being replaced with floating point variables then this will do it:

allvar = '%f %f %f' % (X,Y,Z)

String formatting types (eg '%f') for float can be found here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

If you are working with more complex types than floats, ints, strings, etc or if you need a more compact representation of the string then you could use a serialization protocol like msgpack, json, etc.  However, the remote server would have to be able to unpack the data that's been packed using a serializer.